# CKEDITOR Widgets drag drop into needed element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ckeditor

I have a problem with ckeditor widgets. I have inline non-editable text widget which I can drag drop enywhere in editor (using its default functionality). So I need to check where I'm dropping my widget and if this place is undroppable (according my rules it us TABLE) do cancel events propagations and widget should stay on previous place.

```
editor.widgets.add('customWidgetAdd', {
   inline: true,
   template: '<span class="simplebox">' +
            '<span class="simplebox-title" ></span>' +
        '</span>',
   init: function(){
      var that = this;

            that.widgetData = ko.observable(self.activeWidgetData);

            var subscription = that.widgetData.subscribe(function (value) {                                        
                $(that.element.$).find('.simplebox-title').text(value.name);
                if (that.isSelected) {
                    self.activeWidgetData = value;
                }
            });
            var destroyListener = function(ev){
                subscription.dispose();
            };         
            that.once('destroy', destroyListener);

            that.on('doubleclick', function (evt) {
                editor.execCommand(editAction.command);
            });                

            that.on('select', function (evt){
                that.isSelected = true;
                self.activeWidgetData = that.widgetData();
            });

            that.on('deselect', function (evt){

                try {
                  var endContainer = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0].endContainer.getName();
                } catch (e) {

                }

                that.isSelected = false;
                if (endContainer == 'td' || endContainer == 'th') {

                        //SO here comes the problem. My rule is executed and
//I want CKEDITOR do nothing from here... but stil widget is getting cutted     from DOM and inserted to place where I have dropped it...
                        //that.removeListener('destroy', destroyListener);
                        //that.removeAllListeners();
                        evt.cancel();
                        evt.stop();

                        return false;                        
                }
            });
   }
});
```

Comment: I want **not** to be able to drop inline widget into ckeditors table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution in this situation.
The only one way you can do it is to subscribe to editor's drop event, and cancel it if needed, like:

```
editor.on('contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable(),
        // #11123 Firefox needs to listen on document, because otherwise event won't be fired.
        // #11086 IE8 cannot listen on document.
        dropTarget = (CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.version < 9) || editable.isInline() ? editable : editor.document;

    editable.attachListener(dropTarget, 'drop', function(evt) {
        //do all checks here
    });
});
```

You can find how it works [in CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/plugin46.html) (See code of function **setupDragAndDrop**)

Comment: CKEditor 4.5 will introduce DnD APIs and you will be able to simply listen on editor events (like `drop`, `dragover`, etc). Most of the features are already available on the [major](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major) branch.

Comment: I would like to specify root of document as dropTarget for some drops. Can I do that?